# Path environment variables in Python and Mac OS X when using subprocess.call

Tags: python, macos, path, operating-system

Python (2.6.6 -- EPD 6.3-1 (32-bit)) can not find a binary executable when using

```
call(cmmd, shell=True)
```

On Mac OS 10.6.8, started from Eclipse/Pydev, and returns that sh could not find the executable.  Running

```
print os.environ['PATH']
```

returns the default paths:

`/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

Now, running this executable or the script for that matter from any shell is not a problem and its path is added in /etc/profile, ~/.profile and in /etc/paths

Any ideas on how to configure Pydev? The run configuration seems in order, i.e. it picks up the correct python version.

Note:edited for clarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between a login shell and a non-login shell.  When run by python launched from Eclipse, your shell will start as a non-login shell, which will NOT load the `~/.profile`.  [This article has the details](http://www.admon.org/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell/).  So you need to make sure `os.environ` has the directory where your executable lives in it before you call `subprocess.call` or you can just give an absolute path to the executable, or make sure your shell script (if your executable is just a shell script) uses absolute paths or manages its own PATH environment variable.  You can also pass a dictionary of environment variables to `subprocess.Popen` to get detailed control of the subprocess's environment and many other aspects.

Comment: That article makes it sound like copying environment variables to `~/.bashrc` will make eclipse see them.  So I hard-linked `~/.bashrc` to `~/.bash_profile` and restarted eclipse.  However, from a python script in eclipse, if I print out everything in `os.environ`, I don't see the environment variables defined in `~/.bashrc`.  Are the instructions wrong or am I confused?

Comment: Thanks for the article. Setting /etc/bashrc or ~/.bashrc, however, is not working for me. Current fix is a platform dependent config file with the paths to the executables.

Comment: So what's the best place to set the variables so that they are seen by things in the dock?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x/588442#588442

or

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x/3756686#3756686